# How to display selected photos in a single row collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How do I display selected images from the uiimagepickercontroller like the image shown. I am getting a black area on the collectionview. I'm not even sure using a horizontal uicollectionview is the best approach.

[image: Example]

Comment: didn't understood your requirement, can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using horizontal UICollectionView is affordable idea.
You can make 'Add Picture Button' always located in last if you add it as footer.

To do this, subclass your UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override layoutAttributesForElementsInRect().

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    if let layoutAttributesForElementsInRect = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect), let collectionView = self.collectionView {

      for layoutAttributes in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect {
            if layoutAttributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter {

                let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath.section
                let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(section)

                if numberOfItemsInSection > 0 {
                    let lastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: max(0, numberOfItemsInSection - 1), inSection: section)

                    if let lastCellAttrs = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastCellIndexPath) {
                        var origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin

                        origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(lastCellAttrs.frame)

                        layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024
                        layoutAttributes.frame.origin = origin
                        layoutAttributes.frame.size = layoutAttributes.frame.size
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return layoutAttributesForElementsInRect
    }

    return nil
}
```